# Delphi 10.3.3 WebBroker Linux-64 - Error compiling in linux CentOS 8

Tags: linux, delphi, centos8

```
Module Load: appteste. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $000000000043A2B0. Process appteste (3282)
Module Load: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $00007FFFF7DD5030. Process appteste (3282)
Module Load: linux-vdso.so.1. No Debug Info. Base Address: $0000000000000000. Process appteste (3282)
Module Load: libpthread.so.0. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $00007FFFF7BBA8A0. Process appteste (3282)
Module Load: libgcc_s.so.1. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $00007FFFF799EDC0. Process appteste (3282)
Module Load: libc.so.6. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $00007FFFF75FAAD0. Process appteste (3282)
Module Load: libdl.so.2. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $00007FFFF73D6090. Process appteste (3282)
Module Load: libm.so.6. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $00007FFFF705F510. Process appteste (3282)
Module Load: libicuuc.so. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $00007FFFF6A79E30. Process appteste (3282)
Module Load: libicudata.so.60. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $00007FFFF4E6F4A0. Process appteste (3282)
Module Load: libstdc++.so.6. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $00007FFFF4B69B60. Process appteste (3282)
Module Load: libicui18n.so. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $00007FFFF46E9DC0. Process appteste (3282)
Enter a Command: 
Process appteste (3282)
   - "start" to start the server
Process appteste (3282)
   - "stop" to stop the server
Process appteste (3282)
   - "set port" to change the default port
Process appteste (3282)
   - "status" for Server status
Process appteste (3282)
   - "help" to show commands
Process appteste (3282)
   - "exit" to close the application
Process appteste (3282)
-> Process appteste (3282)
```

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

Compile in Debian, then copy the executable in CentOS, obviously library dependencies should be resolved